# Inconsistent element query with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to use `Cypress` to click a `react-select` element. However, I get very inconsistent results.

[image]

My code for clicking the element is as follows:

```
cy.get('div[class*=container]').contains('Brand').click()
```

Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes if I repeat this line twice (which is kind of hacky...), it works, but on other occasions it doesn't...

What would be the correct and fool-proof way to wait for this element to properly load and click it only then in `Cypress`?

Comment: Can you share the HTML for this element ?

Comment: Well, I'm using `react-select` in a standard way, just `<Select ...myprops />`, nothing special. The `div[class*=container]` comes from inspecting the result in the browser and some experimentation on what responds to `click`.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this [cypress repo](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/npm/react/cypress/component/advanced/react-book-example/src/components/ProductsList.spec.js) and it suggested two way to do the `click()`.

```js
cy.contains('.product', 'First item')
  .find('button.order')
  .click()
  .wait(1000)
```

```js
cy.contains('.product', 'First item')
  .find('button.order')
  .click()
  .click()
```

Comment: For a moment I thought that `.wait()` was solving my issue, but it started failing again... The interesting thing is, I can see that my Select is loaded in the browser, but the test is timing out with an error `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'Brand' within the element: [ <div..css-dyr6gj-container>, 2 more... ] but never did.`. So it's like Cypress fails to detect when the browser updates or somethings similar...

Comment: how about you do a force click `click({force: true})`. Or may be increase the time a bit and check.

Comment: You mean increase the default timeout of 4000ms? I suspect this is not an issue, since as I mentioned, I can clearly see the element loaded on the screen, but Cypress does not detect it, even though Cypress often performs actions even before I have a chance to see the rendered result.

Comment: No I meant in the first case `.wait(1000)`, this value. but I don't think this will work either. How about you try `cy.get('div[class*=container]').contains('Brand').eq(0).click()` or `cy.get('div[class*=container]').contains('Brand').focus().click()`

Answer (score 0):

Because its a select element, what you would want to do is:

```
cy.get('div[class*=container]').select('Brand')
```

or

```
cy.get('div[class*=container]').contains('Brand').realClick()
```

Comment: Sorry Andrew, it seems `.select()` can only be called on an actual native `<select>` html element, which `react-select` isn't. And `.realClick()` doesn't seem to exist in Cypress...

Comment: Sorry about that, was under the impression it was a <select> element. realClick() 
definitely does work in cypress. I use it almost every day.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at examples of [react-select](https://react-select.com/home), there are a lot of classes with `container` in them, so `'div[class*=container]'` is not the best selector.

I understand `class*=container` is to circumvent the style hash which can change on compile.

Ideally, add a specific class to the source, as per the first example on the home page

```js
<Select
  className="basic-single"
  ...
```

then you have a link to the top-most element, which is clickable.

```js
cy.visit('https://react-select.com/home')

cy.get('div.basic-single')
  .should('contain', 'Ocean')
  .click()

cy.contains('Green').click()  // option selection

cy.get('div.select__control').eq(0)
  .should('contain', 'Green')
```